# Samsung Monitor Bx2450 resolution

Tags: display, resolution

I just bought a Samsung BX2450 LED monitor. I use a 1920x1080 resolution at 60Hz which works fine, but it's not using the full display.

There is a 1cm border on the top/bottom and a 1.5cm border on the left/right. In effect I'm only using 22" of my new 24" monitor.

I installed new drivers for my ATI HD 58xx graphics card and monitor but this didn't help.

Here's a diagram to show what I mean:

[image: link to a sample]

The blue area is the actual display of the monitor. If I use a resolution of 1680x1050 then the full display is used but it doesn't look great. If I use 1920x1080 then it uses only the red area of the diagram.

I would hope to end up with a resolution of 1920x1080 filling the blue area.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just wanted to do it a bit more [specific 
reference](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/UnableToSetGPUScaling.aspx):

1. Setting up the resolution to 1280x1024 (this is enable GPU funtion in catalyst control center):

   - Right click on desktop > screen resolution
   - Set up the screen resolution to 1280x1024
   - Keep changes, is going to look bad still.
2. Manually scaling the resolution in Catalyst Control Center:

   - Right click on desktop, catalyst control center;
   - Go to "My digital flat-panels"
   - Properties (Digital Flat-Panel)
   - Tick Enable GPU Scaling and select Scale image to full panel size
   - Go to "My digital flat-panels" and Scaling Options (Digital Flat-Panel)
   - Drag to 0% overscan and Tick Use the scaling values…
   - Apply changes
3. Set up the resolution to 1920x1080:

   - Right click on desktop then click on screen resolution;
   - Set up to to 1920x1080.

Note: A computer restart must be done to apply changes.

Comment: +1 It's a scaling/overscan issue which can be tweaked in the Catalyst Control Center.

Comment: yes that was the problem! THX!

Answer (score 0):

That display is a 16:9 display, not a 16:10.  1920x1080 is it's maximum resolution:

http://www.samsung.com/us/consumer/office/monitors/business/LS24B5HVFH/ZA/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=spec

Comment: i know, what i want is to use the full display of this monitor and not only 22" :D
if i change the resolution to 1680x1050 it uses the full 24" but not on 1920x1080 ;/